# Construct the correct SQL String for ADO to get data with MAX Date

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, ado

I am retrieving data from a closed Excel Binary file using ADO.
I have 2 Sheets in that file and what I want is to retrieve all data from *Sheet1* where ID exist in *Sheet2*.
And I was able to do just that by:

```
sqlstr = "SELECT e.NOTES, u.SPO, e.ID, e.REF, e.PID "
sqlstr = sqlstr & ", e.DESCRIPTION, e.CreateDate "
sqlstr = sqlstr & "FROM [Sheet2$] u "
sqlstr = sqlstr & "INNER JOIN [Sheet1$] e "
sqlstr = sqlstr & "ON e.ID = u.ID;"
```

The problem arise when a specific ID was reflected 2 or more x in Sheet1 but with different dates.
I need to retrieve ID with the highest Data only and so I try below:

```
sqlstr = "SELECT e.NOTES, u.SPO, e.ID, e.REF, e.PID  "
sqlstr = sqlstr & ", e.DESCRIPTION, e.CreateDate "
sqlstr = sqlstr & "FROM [Sheet2$] u "
sqlstr = sqlstr & "INNER JOIN (SELECT ID, REF, PID, DESCRIPTION, NOTES, MAX(CreateDate) "
sqlstr = sqlstr & "FROM [Sheet1$] GROUP BY ID, REF, PID, DESCRIPTION, NOTES) e "
sqlstr = sqlstr & "ON e.ID = u.ID;"
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work and gives me this error:

[image]

I tried isolating my *Sub Query* like this:

```
sqlstr = "SELECT ID, REF, PID, DESCRIPTION, NOTES, MAX(CreateDate) "
sqlstr = sqlstr & "FROM [Sheet1$] GROUP BY ID, REF, PID, DESCRIPTION, NOTES;"
```

It works fine. It returns all ID with the maximum date only.
**My questions are:**

1. Why doesn't it work when I try to use it as *Sub Query*.
2. Does ADO support *Sub Query* when pulling data from Excel files or databases?
3. Is there a way to get the result I wanted using just a query?

Any help is appreciated.

**Clarification:** The *Sub Query* works if I run it using SQL. I was trying to make it work using ADO. This is the first time I'm doing a *Sub Query* in an SQL String for use in opening a *record set*. So I thought maybe I'm doing something wrong or doing something out of the scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be overdoing things.

Try this:

(untested code)

```
SELECT e.NOTES, u.SPO, e.ID, e.REF, e.PID, e.DESCRIPTION, MAX(e.CreateDate) as CreateDate 
FROM [Sheet1$] e  
INNER JOIN [Sheet2$] u ON e.ID = u.ID 
GROUP BY e.ID, e.REF, e.PID, e.DESCRIPTION, e.NOTES, u.SPO
```

Comment: Fantastic though the `as CreateDate` part doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

I would first join `Sheet1` to `Sheet2` followed by joining a subquery which will only have the max created dates. Something like this:

```
SELECT e.NOTES, u.SPO, e.ID, e.REF, e.PID, e.DESCRIPTION, e.CreateDate
FROM [Sheet2$] u

INNER JOIN [Sheet1$] e
ON e.ID = u.ID

INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ID, MAX(CreateDate) AS MaxCD
    FROM [Sheet1$]
    GROUP BY ID
) AS MCD
ON e.ID = MCD.ID
AND e.CreateDate = MCD.MaxCD
```

What this is essentially doing is:

- Joining all results from `Sheet1`
- Joining `Sheet1` again but only with the highest created date.

Comment: Thanks Gareth. This works in SQL. But what I'm trying to do is do execute a query through VBA using ADO. I can't seem to make sub queries work.

Comment: No probs, sub queries will work with ADO. What happened when you tried using the code I posted in your SQL string?

Comment: It says there's a `syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'ON e.ID = u.IDINNER JOIN (SELECT ID, MAX(CreateDate) AS MaxCD FROM [Sheet1$] GROUP BY ID) AS MCD ON e.ID = MCD.ID AND e.CreateDate = MCD.MaxCD'`